# Log4j JDK Logging adapter: Apply LogManager system property late in the startup process

Tags: logging, websphere, log4j2, websphere-liberty, java.util.logging

I have an WebSphere Application Server which runs an WebApp. I start the Server from Eclipse. The main logging framework in that application is log4j2, but there are some third party libraries which use java.util.logging. I want to redirect those logs to log4j2 so it uses my filters, log format etc. To achieve this I can use the [Log4j JDK Logging Adapter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-jul/index.html).

Usually one would set the system property `-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager`, for example in the jvm.options. The problem is that I can't seem to make that solution work because the server uses java util logging long before my log4j2 properties are loaded and before the `log4j-jul` jar of the adapter is loaded. This causes an Exception to be thrown immediatly after trying to start the server (see my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55827925/websphere-could-not-load-logmanager-org-apache-logging-log4j-jul-logmanager/55829921#55829921)).

So I thought maybe it's possible to set the `LogManager` to the one from the `log4j-jul` jar later in the startup process, when the jar is and my log4j2 properties are loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as the [java.util.logging.LogManager](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/logging/LogManager.java) is loaded (near line 174) it assigns the singleton instance.  There is no way to replace it after loading is triggered.

Installing the [org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.Log4jBridgeHandler](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-jul/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/jul/Log4jBridgeHandler.java) should do the trick.  You should be able to add that handler to the root logger using the default LogManager with [WebSphere](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/ctrb_loghandler.html).

Usually this can be done by adding the following to your logging.properties:

```
.handlers=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.Log4jBridgeHandler
.level.INFO
org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.Log4jBridgeHandler.level=ALL
```

Per [LOG4J2-2025](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2025) this is fixed in LOG4J2 version 3.0.0.  As of  Oct 23, 2021, it appears that this issue was backported in [LOG4J2-2025 jul-log4j bridgehandler](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/pull/437) into 2.15.0.  For LOG4J2 2.3 you can use [log4j2-Java6-extras](https://gitlab.com/thiesw/log4j2-Java6-extras) or [download log4j2-Java6-extras from Maven](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:de.it-tw%20AND%20a:log4j2-Java6-extras).

Comment: I am confused - from your link it looks like the Log4jBridgeHandler is part of log4j-jul, but I downloaded the jars of the last couple of versions and there is no such class inside. findjar has no result for the class either. Can you tell me how I can obtain the class? Or should I just code copy it?

Comment: For now I tested it with a code copy of the Log4jBridgeHandler class and it works just fine!

Comment: org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:2.18 contains this class Log4jBridgeHandler